# Why is $K((X))$ free module over $K((X^q))$ with basis $1,X,X^2,・・・,X^{q-1}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

Let $K$ be a field. Why is $K((X))$ free module over $K((X^q))$ with basis $1,X,X^2,・・・,X^{q-1}$ ?

I want to prove this.

My try :
[$K((X)):K((X^q))]＝q$, so $1,X,X^2,・・・,X^{q}$ is linearly dependent.

Comment: Don't you have an explicit description of the elements as formal Laurent series? The linear independence and basis are a bit obvious then ($\Bbb{F}_q$ doesn't have any role, it could be any field $k$)

Comment: Yes, but I want to discuss with extension degree.

Comment: If $F(a)/F$ is a field extension and $[F(a):F]=n$ then the $a^j,j\in 0 \ldots n-1$ are a $F$-vector space basis of $F(a)$.